# Generic Custom Join Extension Method

Tags: c#, linq, generics, join, extension-methods

Let's say we have 2 tables, `TableA` and `TableB` with a PK-FK relationship amongst them, I have written an `extension method` to `join` these 2 tables and fetch the data. This extension method is quite specific, and gets the work done for these very 2 tables.

What needs to be done to create a GENERIC extension method to join any two tables, and project the data?

My code:

Schema of `TableA`:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TableA](
    [Id_1] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Address] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id_1] ASC
)
```

Schema of `TableB`:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TableB](
    [Id_2] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name2] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Address2] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [FK_Id] [int] NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id_2] ASC
)
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TableB]  WITH CHECK ADD FOREIGN KEY([FK_Id])
REFERENCES [dbo].[TableA] ([Id_1])
```

C# code:

```
public class ABDTO
   {
       public TableA A { get; set; }
       public TableB B { get; set; }
    }

public static class Helper
    {
        public static IEnumerable<ABDTO> Join(this IEnumerable<TableA> tableA,IEnumerable<TableB> tableB)
        {
           return tableA.Join(tableB,x => x.Id_1,y => y.FK_Id,
                                    (x, y) =>new ABDTO
                                         {
                                             A = x,
                                              B = y
                                          });
                }

public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Operation1();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static void Operation1()
        {
            using (var db = new SampleEntities())
            {
                var result = db.TableAs.Join(db.TableBs);

                foreach(var item in result)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}; {1} ||| {2} ; {3}", item.A.Id_1, item.A.Name, item.B.Id_2, item.B.Name2);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

So, `Join()` is an `extension method`, which takes in `TableA` and `TableB`, joins them on the PK-FK relationship and projects out the selectors.

How can I write something `generic` as :

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Join(this IEnumerable<T> Ta, IEnumerable<T> Tb)
        {
            return Ta.Join(Tb, x => Ta.SomeColumn1, y => Tb.SomeColumn2,
                                (x, y) => Projection of columns);
        }
```

I am not very good in `LINQ` and `Extension methods`, please help.
Any pointers will also be helpful.

Comment: Did you try accepting column names as parameters? If you have Func<> delegate as parameters for 'Join' method.. from the calling code you can provide which column you want to use for join, so no need to hard code them inside 'Join' extension.

Comment: @ SIva Gopal...I don't get you properly..Can you please explain more?

Comment: Seems that you're looking for an automated way to discover "joinable" columns. The problem is: how would any automated procedure know what you want to join? Only by name convention (equal names)?

Comment: How is the extension method an improvement over `Join` itself?  Seems like you're missing the join criteria parameters and result definition, but adding those would give you effectively the same syntax as `Join`, so I'm not sure what improvement you're trying to make.

Comment: You really shouldn't be performing this join in memory; you should be doing this join within the database.

Answer (score 0):

I did some R&D and was able to deduce the solution.

```
public class ABDTO<T,U> 
    {
        public T A { get; set; }
        public U B { get; set; }
    }
    public static class Helper
    {
        public static IQueryable<ABDTO<T,U>> JoinEx<T,U,Key>(this IQueryable<T> tableA,IQueryable<U> tableB, Expression<Func<T, Key>> column1, Expression<Func<U, Key>> column2)
        {
            return tableA.Join(tableB, column1, column2, (y, z) => new ABDTO<T,U> {A= y, B=z });
        }
    }
```

`JoinEx<>()` is a generic `extension` method which takes into 2 tables of types `T` and `U`, join them on the basis of 2 columns, and project out the result in some common `DTO`.

It's called as below:

```
using (var db = new SampleEntities())
            {
                var result=db.TableAs.JoinEx<TableA, TableB, int>(db.TableBs, x => x.Id_1, y => y.FK_Id);  
                foreach(var item in result)
                {               
                        Console.WriteLine("{0} \t {1}",item.A.Name,item.B.Name2);                                       
                }
            }
```

I understand that there maybe performance constraints, and these kind of operations must be performed in the `database` as a `stored procedure`, but there's a requirement for this sort of generic stuff.

Thanks